What GLM family and link I should use for the left skewed dependent variable?
From what I read, the Generalized Linear Model (GLM) is flexible in accommodating a variety of error distributions. To effectively utilize GLM, it is important to select an appropriate family and link function that corresponds to the distribution of my dependent variable. My dependent variable exhibits positive continuity but is negatively skewed. I would like to ask for help in finding the suitable GLM family and link function to use, as it appears that these families are generally better suited for positively skewed data. Below is an image the distribution of my dependent variable. Thank you!
Distribution of my dependent variable which is left skewed
I did search what type of family I should use for left skewed but nothing tells.
